# Sort a list of dictionaries by multiple keys/values, where the order of the values should be specific

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary, lambda

I have a list of dictionaries and want each item to be sorted by a specific property values.

The list:

```
[
{'name':'alpha', status='run'},
{'name':'alpha', status='in'}, 
{'name':'alpha-32', status='in'},
{'name':'beta', status='out'}
{'name':'gama', status='par'}
{'name':'gama', status='in'}
{'name':'aeta', status='run'}
{'name':'aeta', status='unknown'}
{'pname': 'boc', status='run'}
]
```

I know I can do:

```
newlist = sorted(init_list, key=lambda k: (k['name'], k['status'])
```

but there two more conditions:

1. If the key `name` is no present in a dict, for the name to be used the value corresponding to `pname` key.
2. the `status` order to be `['out', 'in', 'par', 'run']`
3. if the `status` value doesn't correspond with what is in the list, ignore it - see `unknown`;

The result should be:

```
[
{'name':'aeta', status='unknown'}
{'name':'aeta', status='run'}
{'name':'alpha', status='in'},
{'name':'alpha', status='run'},
{'name':'alpha-32', status='in'},
{'name':'beta', status='out'},
{'pname': 'boc', status='run'}
{'name':'gama', status='in'},
{'name':'gama', status='par'}
]
```

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the key function? If it becomes too complex it is better to write a regular function than a lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
from itertools import count
# Use count() instead of range(4) so that we
# don't need to worry about the length of the status list.

newlist = sorted(init_list,
                 key=lambda k: (k.get('name', k.get('pname')),
                                dict(zip(['out', 'in', 'par', 'run'], count())
                                    ).get(k['status'], -1)
                                )
                )
```

If `k['name']` doesn't exits, fall back to `k['pname']` (or `None` if *that* doesn't exist). Likewise, if there is no known integer for the given status, default to -1.

I deliberately put this all in one logical line to demonstrate that at this point, you may want to just define the `key` function using a `def` statement.

```
def list_order(k):
    name_to_use = k.get('name')
    if name_to_use is None:
        name_to_use = k['pname']  # Here, just assume pname is available

    # Explicit definition; you might still write
    # status_orders = dict(zip(['out', ...], count())),
    # or better yet a dict comprehension like
    # { status: rank for rank, status in enumerate(['out', ...]) }
    status_orders = {
        'out': 0,
        'in': 1,
        'par': 2,
        'run': 3
    }

    status_to_use = status_orders.get(k['status'], -1)

    return name_to_use, status_to_use

newlist = sorted(init_list, key=list_order)
```

Comment: hmm, it was a nice one-liner with the `zip` +1 :) I see you've changed it to `enumerate` now, but it won't work it, since it puts the indexes as keys in the dict

Comment: Oh, right. I changed it after I saw you use it, and wondered why I hadn't in the first place. But you correctly swapped the order :)

Answer (score 2):

The first condition is simple, you get default the first value of the ordering tuple to `pname`, i.e.

```py
lambda k: (k.get('name', k.get('pname')), k['status'])
```

For the second and third rule I would define an order dict for statuses

```py
status_order = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(['out', 'in', 'par', 'run'])}
```

and then use it in key-function

```py
lambda k: (k.get('name', k.get('pname')), status_order.get(k['status']))
```

I haven't tested it, so it might need some tweaking